# iOS CMake and XCode 6 "no such product type for 'iphoneos'"

Tags: ios, cmake

When I generate a library project and try to compile it I get:

```
target specifies product type 'com.apple.product-type.tool', but there's no such product type for the 'iphoneos' platform
```

From what I understand that is a product type that is only available on Mac OS and not iOS, is that correct? How is it possible to fix it? I cannot find any clue.

Comment: I actually converted all of the types to `com.apple.product-type.bundle.unit-test` and it worked well.